# how to count two conditions on the same group

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to write an sql query that will show to

1) every component with name starting with 'myTeam'

2) of type "Bug"

3) How many bugs were opened this month and how many were verified afterwords from that group?

Here is my code:

```
select 
histories.component_path,
count distinct bug_id as id1 from buganizer.metadata.latest WHERE (histories.component_path LIKE 'myTeam >%' And type_id = 'BUG' And (date - Now() < 30) ) as total_bugs,
count distinct bug_id as id2 from buganizer.metadata.latest WHERE (histories.component_path LIKE 'myTeam >%' And type_id = 'BUG' And status_id = 'VERIFIED') as verified_bugs
```

how can I make this shorted and more well formatted?

Comment: You should really show us table structure along with some sample data.

Comment: If this works then it ain't MySQL

Comment: @Strawberry  i don't think this code work .. is not SQL .. too

Comment: @scaisEdge Maybe. I couldn't say.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your query like below. COUNT won't consider the NULL values. Could you try the query *(it is not verified)*

```
SELECT  A.component_path, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT A.id1) AS total_bugs,
        COUNT(DISTINCT A.id2) AS verified_bugs
FROM (
    SELECT 
        histories.component_path AS component_path,
        CASE WHEN (DATE - NOW() < 30) THEN bug_id ELSE NULL END AS id1,
        CASE WHEN status_id = 'VERIFIED' THEN bug_id ELSE NULL END AS id2
    FROM buganizer.metadata.latest 
    -- need to add some join with "histories" table
    WHERE histories.component_path LIKE 'myTeam%' AND type_id = 'BUG'
) AS A
GROUP BY A.component_path
```